# JsonArray.getvaluesAs doesn't take String.class as parameter

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm using `javax.Json.JsonArray` object.

method: `javax.Json.JsonArray.getvaluesAs(Class<T>)` returns the `JsonArray` as List. So what I want to do is to get the `List` into a `Set`. this is what I do:

```
Set values= new HashSet(myjsonArray.getValuesAs(null));
```

This works fine, but I know  that `myjsonArray` only contains `String`. so what I really want to do is :

```
Set<String> values= new HashSet(myjsonArray.getValuesAs(String.class));
```

For some reason for the above code I get compiler error:

```
The generic method getValuesAs(Class<T>) of type JsonArray is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>). The inferred type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends JsonValue>
```

I can get my `Set<String>` built using loops, but I try to avoid that, so is there an easy fix for above error?

Comment: @aegean Hmm tried it, it get the same error.

Comment: If anyone read this: don't use javax.Json.JsonArray class, it is about to make me cry...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The getValuesAs() method only supports classes that extends JsonValue. In this case you can use JsonString.class which then casts simply to a String.

Check this (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html#getValuesAs-java.lang.Class-) and you could see that T extends JsonValue

Answer (score 1):

As [Nine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5288799/nine) said "*getValuesAs() method only supports classes that extends JsonValue*"

Here it is my work around (and the only possible) for this problem:

```
private static List<String> toList(JsonArray json){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (json != null){
        for (JsonString elm: json.getValuesAs(JsonString.class)){
            list.add(elm.getString());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `getValuesAs(JsonString.class).stream().map(JsonString::getString).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: `List<String> list = jsonArray.getValuesAs(JsonString::getString);`

Is even shorter...

Answer (score 0):

I used this library a long time ago. 
From what i remember, you can only pass a class into the "getValuesAs()" method that extends from JsonValue. Thats why string isn't working. You will have to try another method. 
Sorry, I don't remmeber which method it was.